# How to capitalize vowels that are reversed?

Tags: python, function, for-loop

Working on a homework question that requires us to make a function where all the vowels in a string are reversed. example: `This Is So Fun` would return `Thus Os Si Fin`. Just can't figure out how to make the function detect the where the uppercase letters are to convert them into lowercase and vice versa. Right now the function outputs `Thus os SI Fin`

```
def f(word):
    vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
    string = list(word)
    i = 0
    j = len(word)-1

    while i < j:
        if string[i].lower() not in vowels:
            i += 1
        elif string[j].lower() not in vowels:
            j -= 1
        else:
            string[i], string[j] = string[j], string[i]
            i += 1
            j -= 1

    return "".join(string)
```

Comment: So in the example of 'This Is So Fun' the vowels are (i,I,o,u). Don't want to touuch any letters around it but I want them to be put back in reverse order which is (u,o,I,i). Issue being that I can't figure out how to put them back so they're uppercase where they need to be and lowercase where they need to be.

Comment: An easy solution is to go over your final string and detect if any vowel comes right after a space. If so, convert to uppercase, if not, to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

How I would/did approach it

- go through, grab the vowels
- reiterate over the string, rebuilding it with a reversed vowel list
- when inserting a vowel, check the case of the original character in that position

Edit: since everyone is providing a solution, I thought I too would provide a solution.

This is how I achieved the same goal:

1. Iterate through the string and grab the vowels
2. Go through the string a second time, swapping out the reversed vowels

   ```
   str="This Is So Fun"
   print(str)
   vowels=[]
   for letter in str:
       if letter.lower() in "aeiou":
           vowels.append(letter.lower())

   out = ""
   for letter in str:
       if letter.lower() in "aeiou":
           if letter.isupper():
               out += vowels.pop().upper()
           else:
               out += vowels.pop().lower()
       else:
           out += letter

   print(out)
   ```

Comment: The issue with this is when I try to use this on other strings which don't have letters capitalized at the start of a word, if affects them too which I don't want it to.

Comment: I phrased the question wrong, I don't want strings which don't have every word with an uppercase letter to be affected. For example given the string 'Hello world' I would like it to return 'Hollo werld'

Comment: Yes, on the second iteration, check the ‘is upper’  value of the string character, and put the replaced character into that position, copying the case of the original. See revised code

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be to check the two letters that you are replacing. If their case is the same, then you don't need to do anything, but if their case is not the same, you would switch their case before you switch the letters.

I am not sure if you need it, but this approach is a bit more flexible than @Madivad's answer as it allows you to pass strings with capitalizations anywhere within the string such as `This Is SoO FunIE` -> `Thes Is SuO FonII`

An easy way to do it is to check the capitalization with `str.isupper()` method and then do the reversal with an if/else case

```
if string[i].isupper() != string[j].isupper():
  if string[i].isupper():
     string[j], string[i] = string[j].upper(), string[i].lower()
  else:
     string[j], string[i] = string[j].lower(), string[i].upper()
```

Finalyl you would incorporate this snippet it in your code just above your string replacement:

```
def f(word):
    vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
    string = list(word)
    i = 0
    j = len(word)-1

    while i < j:
        if string[i].lower() not in vowels:
            i += 1
        elif string[j].lower() not in vowels:
            j -= 1
        else:
            if string[i].isupper() != string[j].isupper():
                if string[i].isupper():
                    string[j], string[i] = string[j].upper(), string[i].lower()
                else:
                    string[j], string[i] = string[j].lower(), string[i].upper()
            string[i], string[j] = string[j], string[i]
            i += 1
            j -= 1

    return "".join(string)
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make a small function that takes two characters and returns each with the other's case you can simply wrap your assignment in that:

```
def swapCase(c1, c2):
    return  (
        c1.upper() if c2.isupper() else c1.lower(), 
        c2.upper() if c1.isupper() else c2.lower()
    )


def f(word):
    vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
    string = list(word)
    i = 0
    j = len(word)-1

    while i < j:
        if string[i].lower() not in vowels:
            i += 1
        elif string[j].lower() not in vowels:
            j -= 1
        else:
            string[i], string[j] = swapCase(string[j], string[i])
            i += 1
            j -= 1

    return "".join(string)

f("This Is So Fun")
# 'Thus Os Si Fin'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below approach:

The idea is as below:

- First get the list of vowels into a list
- Next, try to interchange them
- Now, iterate through the input and change the vowels while checking the original case of the vowels in the input

**Note:** I have not done a complete a testing for all cases. You will have to probably check and handle it yourself.

```
    def f(word):

        vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
        vowels_in_word = [x for x in word if x in vowels]
        word_list = list(word)
        print("Vowels in word in order = %s" %(vowels_in_word))

        i = 0
        j = len(vowels_in_word)-1
        while i <= j:
            vowels_in_word[i], vowels_in_word[j] = vowels_in_word[j], vowels_in_word[i]
            i += 1
            j -= 1

        print("Changed Vowels = %s" %(vowels_in_word))

        i = 0
        j = 0
        for x in word_list:
            if x in vowels:
                if x.islower():
                    word_list[i] = vowels_in_word[j].lower()
                else:
                    word_list[i] = vowels_in_word[j].upper()

                j += 1

            i += 1

        result_str = ''.join(x for x in word_list)
        print("Result Str = %s" %(result_str))

    f("This Is So Fun")
```

**Output:**

```
Vowels in word in order = ['i', 'I', 'o', 'u']
Changed Vowels = ['u', 'o', 'I', 'i']
Result Str = Thus Os Si Fin
```